# Transforming data on the Principal Components axis?

Tags: self-study, pca, projection

```
x     y
2.5  2.4
0.5  0.7
2.2  2.9
1.9  2.2
3.1  3.0
2.3  2.7
2    1.6
1    1.1
1.5  1.6
1.1  0.9
```

Eigenvalues:

```
     .0490
     1.2840
```

Eigenvectors:

```
-.7352    -.6779
 .6779    -.7352
```

Now how would I project my original x,y data onto the new axis or eigenvectors sometimes called transformed data?

```
1.using one single eigenvector.
2.using both eigenvectors
```

refer to page 18 and 19 of the link.
    [PCA Tutorial](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf)

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I have no idea what this question is supposed to mean. If it's a question from a course of a textbook, please provide the exact quote.

Comment: link added.It is in page 18 and 19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take each datapoint $\mathbf{z}_i = [x_i, y_i]$ and project it onto the two eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$. Because the eigenvectors are of unit length, this is simply the dot product:

$$w^{(1)}_i = \mathbf{z}_i^T \mathbf{v}_1 = -0.7352x_i + 0.6779y_i$$
$$w^{(2)}_i = \mathbf{z}_i^T \mathbf{v}_2 = -0.6779x_i - 0.7352y_i$$

Where $w^{(1)}_i$ is the projection of datapoint $i$ onto the first principal component and $w^{(2)}_i$ is the projection onto the second component. These $w$'s are the new "transformed" coordinates - try plotting the data in this space.

See this Khan academy video for an intro to linear projection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=27vT-NWuw0M

Comment: Bravo............thanx man that was kicking my ass very hard..